# load a downloadable link into a browser in android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a downloadable link something like this `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0Bw6vr2LNxB3iUFJrTk5oZDljaTA&export=download`  which only works on browser.

if i open the link using the mobile browser using this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Then it automatically download the file.

Is it possible to download the file using the webview instead of default browser??

i tried with something like this

```
    public class showDownload extends Activity {
private WebView webView;
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_download);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras.getString("url") != null) {
    //DO SOMETHING

        String url=extras.getString("url");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "__", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {            
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                        long contentLength) {
         Request request = new Request(
                                    Uri.parse(url));
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Yesssss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download"); 
                            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                            dm.enqueue(request);        

                }
            });

    }

   }
```

}

I tired a lot but cant get any solution ?
Can any one help me to solve this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have like an in app download manager, refer to this post.
Provides you very detailed info about the various download options.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660

Comment: If i pass the url into my browser or my mobile browser then it automatically download the file. I dont want to open any browser so i want to download the file using the webview . is it possible ? @siris_cac

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't verify what kind of download link it is but we here have two options if you want to download a file using webview -

1. `DownloadManager` [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17095159/609782)
2. `DownloadListener` [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10069265/609782)

I will check both of them and will come back to you, till then you may start with `DownloadListener` first, as I have used it before and it worked well.

```
    mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
 Request request = new Request(
                            Uri.parse(url));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download"); 
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);        

        }
    });
```

Comment: The user will not click anywhere in the webView . I just pass the url to the webview then it will automatically download the file thats what i want.  But using ur link user needs to open the browser and cant back to the app without closing  it. @Darpan

Comment: I have updated my code for a while, first set a `Log` in `DownloadListener` so that you could verify your `webView` is able to catch this download. If answer is yes, then you may go ahead with my newly updated code, if answer is 'no', then I will update with other alternative.

Comment: But it needs to open the browser which i dont want @Darpan

Comment: No it does not, it opens in webview. I have tried it.

Comment: Hey @Darpan , have u found any solution or not ?

Comment: I am in office, will take time to figure that out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79302/discussion-between-darkenshooter-and-darpan).

Answer (score 0):

on your button click stuff

```
String URL = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0Bw6vr2LNxB3iUFJrTk5oZDljaTA&export=download";

//check if your device is marshmallow that need runtime permission
return(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);

String[] perms = {"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
int permsRequestCode = 200;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
     requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);
}
```

and call `onRequestPermissionsResult` method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){

    switch(permsRequestCode){

        case 200:

            boolean writeAccepted = grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

            //if user click allow, it will start downloading the file from URL
            if (writeAccepted) {
                new DownloadTask(MainActivity.this, URL);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you have no permission!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            break;

    }

}
```

now create a java class called `DownloadTask.java`

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;


public class DownloadTask {

    private static final String TAG = "Download Task";
    private Context context;

    private String downloadUrl = "", downloadFileName = "";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public DownloadTask(Context context, String downloadUrl) {
        this.context = context;

        this.downloadUrl = downloadUrl;


        downloadFileName = "yourfilename_" + uploadDate() + rand() + ".pdf"; //Create file name by picking download file name from URL
        Log.e(TAG, downloadFileName);

        //Start Downloading Task
        new DownloadingTask().execute();
    }

    private String uploadDate() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

        return formattedDate;
    }

    private String rand() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return String.format("%09d", random.nextInt(10000000));
    }

    private class DownloadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        File apkStorage = null;
        File outputFile = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            try {
                if (outputFile != null) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Download successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //this is to view the downloaded file
                    File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "yourfoldername" + "/" + downloadFileName);
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
                    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                    pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    try{
                        context.startActivity(pdfIntent);
                    }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "no apps can read the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } else {

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Download failed. Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, 3000);

                    Log.e(TAG, "Download Failed");

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                //Change button text if exception occurs

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                }, 3000);
                Log.e(TAG, "Download Failed with Exception - " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

            }


            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(downloadUrl);//Create Download URl
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//Open Url Connection
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");//Set Request Method to "GET" since we are grtting data
                c.connect();//connect the URL Connection

                //If Connection response is not OK then show Logs
                if (c.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Server returned HTTP " + c.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + c.getResponseMessage());

                }


                //Get File if SD card is present
                if (new CheckForSDCard().isSDCardPresent()) {

                    apkStorage = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                                + "yourfoldername");
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Oops!! There is no SD Card.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //If File is not present create directory
                if (!apkStorage.exists()) {
                    apkStorage.mkdir();
                    Log.e(TAG, "Directory Created.");
                }

                outputFile = new File(apkStorage, downloadFileName);//Create Output file in Main File

                //Create New File if not present
                if (!outputFile.exists()) {
                    outputFile.createNewFile();
                    Log.e(TAG, "File Created");
                }

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);//Get OutputStream for NewFile Location

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();//Get InputStream for connection

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];//Set buffer type
                int len1 = 0;//init length
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);//Write new file
                }

                //Close all connection after doing task
                fos.close();
                is.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                //Read exception if something went wrong
                e.printStackTrace();
                outputFile = null;
                Log.e(TAG, "Download Error Exception " + e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```